# Equation for four-acceleration

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, acceleration, vectors

Wikipedia states that

$$ \begin{align} \mathbf{A} =\frac{d\mathbf{U}}{d\tau}
&= \left(\gamma_u\dot\gamma_u c,\gamma_u^2\mathbf a+\gamma_u\dot\gamma_u\mathbf u\right) \\
&= \left(\gamma_u^4\frac{\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{u}}{c},
  \gamma_u^2\mathbf{a}+\gamma_u^4\frac{\left(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{u}\right)}{c^2}\mathbf{u}\right) \\
&= \left(\gamma_u^4\frac{\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{u}}{c}, \gamma_u^4\left(\mathbf{a}+\frac{\mathbf{u}\times \left(\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{a}\right)}{c^2}\right)\right).
\end{align} $$

I understand the first two lines perfectly. But I don't see how the gamma squared in the second line becomes gamma to the fourth in the third line. Am I missing something

Comment: have you expanded the double rotational to see the result?

Comment: I dont understand. Looking at the last term in the second equation "a dot u" is a scalar. The result should be gamma to the fourth times u (times a scalar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with:
$$\gamma^2\,\boldsymbol a+\gamma^4\frac{\boldsymbol a\cdot \boldsymbol u}{c^2}\boldsymbol u=\gamma^4\left(\frac{1}{\gamma^2}\boldsymbol a+\frac{\boldsymbol a\cdot \boldsymbol u}{c^2}\boldsymbol u\right)$$

and : $$\gamma^2=\frac{1}{1-\frac {\boldsymbol u \cdot \boldsymbol u}{c^2}}$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$\left(\frac{1}{\gamma^2}\boldsymbol a+\frac{\boldsymbol a\cdot \boldsymbol u}{c^2}\boldsymbol u\right)=\boldsymbol a+\frac{\boldsymbol u\times 
(\boldsymbol u\times \boldsymbol a)}{c^2}$$

**Edit:**

use the identity

$$\boldsymbol u\times (\boldsymbol u\times \boldsymbol a)=(\boldsymbol u\cdot \boldsymbol a)\boldsymbol u-(\boldsymbol u\cdot \boldsymbol u)\,\boldsymbol a$$

Comment: Concise and effective answer. +1